# TypeError: app.$axios is undefined in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have a `main.js` file which creates an `app` and adds various things to it like `router`, `store`, and `axios`.

This is what I'm doing to add `axios` globally:

```
import {createSSRApp, createApp, h} from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios'    

 const rootComponent = {
        render: () => h(App),
        components: { App }
    }

const app = createApp(rootComponent);
app.config.globalProperties.$axios=axios;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.$axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'; // This throws an error
}
```

When I run this in the browser using `webpack-dev-server`, I am getting an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: app.$axios is undefined

Why does `app.$axios` not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the global property is available on the instance not the prototype.

[docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties)

> ### `globalProperties`
>
> *Adds a global property that can be accessed in any component instance inside the application. The component’s property will take priority when there are conflicting keys.*

So you can use it inside the app or component instances with `this`

```js
this.$axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
```

or if you're using it outside the app instance, you can access it the same way as you defined

```js
// in the same file, since you have the axios object already
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'; 

// or from somewhere else
app.config.globalProperties.$axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
```